# Панель браузера на мобильном телефоне перекрывает часть сайта

Tags: html, css

в мобильной версии сайта панель браузера перекрывает поле ввода

Советовали попробовать

```
height: 100%;
height: -moz-available;
height: -webkit-fill-available;
height: fill-available;
```

Без результатно.

Код https://codepen.io/BPOH/pen/qBREbXL
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сердцу радостно повторять Святые Имена.

Comment: На первом скриншоте панелью перекрыто поле ввода, на втором скриншоте убрана панель браузера видно поле ввода, пробовал на разных телефонах и разные браузеры одно и тоже